# Calculate percentage in Dataframe according to a condition

Tags: r

Assume I have the following Dataframe. I need to count the percentage of ages under 18, grouped by ID and Group. 
What I need is for example for **1 a 50%** or for 3 a 0%
I could do it in two steps by counting all and counting under 18 ages, then merge these two frames toghether, but I want to know if I could do it in one step.

```
a <- group_by(ID, Group ) %>% summarize(countAllData = n())
b <- group_by(ID, Group ) %>% filter(lebensalter < 18) %>%     summarize(countUnder18 = n())
merge(a, b, by=c("ID", "Group"), all=TRUE)
final[is.na(final)] <- 0 
percentageUnder18 = ((final$countUnder18/final$countAllData) * 100)
cbind(final, roundedPercentage)
```

Any suggestion?

```
ID Group Age
1  a      20
1  a      17 
1  b      16
2  c      23
2  c      11
2  d      12
3  e      20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the mean of the indicator variable `Age < 18`.  The last line is optional but the output in this example looks a bit better if you use it.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
   group_by(ID, Group) %>% 
   summarize("%Under18" = round(100 * mean(Age < 18))) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   as.data.frame
```

giving:

```
  ID Group %Under18
1  1     a       50
2  1     b      100
3  2     c       50
4  2     d      100
5  3     e        0
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
ID Group Age
1  a      20
1  a      17 
1  b      16
2  c      23
2  c      11
2  d      12
3  e      20"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain why the mean works here when counting observations? Median also seems to produce the same result.

Comment: Let x be Age < 18 and let xn be the same vector except replacing TRUE with 1 and FALSE with 0.  Then mean(x) = sum(x) / length(x) = sum(xn) / length(x) = { no of 1's in xn } / length(x) = { no of TRUE values in x } / length(x).  Note that mean(x) != median(x) in general  Try it with `mean(c(1, 1, 2))` and `median(c(1, 1, 2))`

Comment: Ach. What patience you have! Thank you.  a:mean(c(0,1))=.5;  b:(mean(1))=1;  c: mean(c(0,1))=.5; d:mean(1)=1;  e:mean(0)=0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate`, i.e.

```
aggregate(Age ~ ID+Group, df, FUN = function(i) sum(i < 18)/length(i))
```

which gives,

```
   ID Group Age
1  1     a 0.5
2  1     b 1.0
3  2     c 0.5
4  2     d 1.0
5  3     e 0.0
```